# Getting 'argument p is missing' error when trying to render an indicative arrow in each row of shiny DataTable. How can I fix this?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to put indicative arrow in one of the cells in each row of data table based upon comparing two columns of the same data table. When I am rendering the data table, I am unable to see the indicative arrow in the cell.
I am getting the below error: -
Error in style(color = "gray") : argument "p" is missing, with no default

I am expecting that based upon comparison of 2 columns in same data table, the specified cell of a particular column in each row should have an indicative arrow(up/down) based upon the comparison. In each row, my script should compare Simulated and Current gross sales numbers and based upon comparison, it should show an indicative arrow in Simulated Gross sales cell for that particular row.
Below is part of my code where I am trying to add the indicative arrow: -

```
formattable(df,  list(
      `Manufacturer` = formatter("span",
                                   style = ~ style(color = "gray")), 
      `Sim_Gross_Sales$`= formatter("span", style = ~ style(color = ifelse(`Sim_Gross_Sales$` >`Cur_Gross_Sales$`, "red", "green")),
                        ~ icontext(ifelse(`Sim_Gross_Sales$` >`Cur_Gross_Sales$`,"arrow-up", "arrow-down"), `Sim_Gross_Sales$`))
      
    ))
    
    DT::datatable(dt,
                  extensions = 'Buttons',
                  rownames = F,
                  escape = F,
                  #editable = list(target = "cell", disable = list(columns = c(0:2, 4:16))),
                  selection = "none",
                  options = list(
                    filter = 'top',
                    pageLength = 30, 
                    scrollY = "200px",
                    autoWidth = F, 
                    scrollX=T, 
                    dom = 'Bftip', 
                    buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel'),
                    columnDefs = list(
                      list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all"),
                      list(width = '100px', targets = "_all"))
                  )
    )
```

Comment: I guess you probably mixed functions with the same name from different packages. since you didn't give the `sessionInfo()`. Try use `formattable::style()` to replace all the `style()` call and see what happens.